# Hessian of $f(x) = e^{u^Tx}$ for some $u\in \mathbb{R^d}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I'm seeing the hessian is $uu^Te^{u^Tx}$. From my understanding since this is a single variable function, we can basically treat $u^T$ as a constant and the hessian is equivalent to the second derivative of f(x) with respect to x. My question is why is the solution $uu^Te^{u^Tx}$ and not $u^Tu^Te^{u^Tx}$.  Is this because the vector dimensions for $u^Tu^T$ don't work for multiplication? - If that's the case, why can we just swap $u^Tu^T$ with $uu^T$?

Comment: Well we have to understand why the Jacobian was $u^Te^{u^Tx}$ in the first place. Order doesn't matter for dot products so it is equally accurate to say $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} e^{x^Tu} = u^Te^{x^Tu}$, but not $u e^{x^Tu}$. Why do you think that is?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=(x_1,....,x_d)$ and $u=(u_1,...,u_d).$ Then:

$$f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^d e^{x_ju_j}.$$

This gives

$$f_{x_k}=u_kf(x).$$

and

$$f_{x_ix_k}=u_iu_kf(x).$$

Thus the Hessian is given by

$$uu^Tf(x)=uu^Te^{u^Tx}.$$